# How to render an angular route from node server?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am newbie in angular+node(express) project. I have an angular app with four pages, I have placed that app folder under Public folder of node_modules folder. I am able to access home directory with url "localhost:8081/#/". Now from server.js(node server) I want to load a new page and also want to send some data to display on that page. Following is the code I've written. I have already built pages for website in angular. so I dont want to use jade or ejs. Tell me the way to do it correctly.

```
app.post('/authenticate',urlencodedParser,function(req,res){
var temp;
res.render( '/#/dashboard', { temp:"tempdata" } );
});
```

I want to go to a page to which route localhost:8081/#/dashboard is pointing with data temp.

Comment: Bettter approach would be to use app.use(express.static());

Comment: I have already put app.use(express.static('public'));

Comment: That's not the way to go, Angular has own routes for frontend Node has own routes for backend. In Angular you should setup the dashboard route and there you should ask Node to give you the tempdata via http call.

Comment: I am using ui-router to dynamicly load and create states for example i am loading a menu.html / menu.ctrl / and menu.service and creaty dynamic state depending which rights the user has $stateprovider allows you to create dynamic states

Comment: I have setup the routes in angular. Basically I want to submit login form to server and load dashboard page with data temp. why do I need to handle routes in client as well as server side

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrongly. NodeJS should only be used to serve index page and all routing shoud be handled in frontend only. Use angular-route or ui-routes to handle routing.

**Serving index page(NodeJS):**

```
app.route('/').get(res.render('index'));
```

**Creating Routes(Angularjs):**

```
angular.module('core').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        // About state routing
        $stateProvider.
        state('dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'dashboard.html'
        }).state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })  
    }
]);
```